# How many join have in SQL?

Tags: sql, join

I am using inner join, left outer join, right outer join and full join in SQL. is there have any other type of join in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various types of "joins" but some of them are the same type with just different names.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) and [self join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join).

The wikipedia article on [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) is quite good.

Comment: Self join isn't really another type of join though, is it? It's worth noting that you can do it, but a self join can be any one of the join types.

Comment: @Bennor - Not strictly, no. But conceptually, some might not consider a join to the same table otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's worth noting. Could mean an incorrect answer if this is homework though (which is what it looks like). :)

Comment: @Bennor - If it is homework (yes, it seems likely) then it is up to him to do some research and gain some understanding. Quoting other verbatim should cause him problems ;)